# How to display Poll results on most recent poll block

Tags: blocks, polls

I'm using most recent poll block to display polling in fronend. After i closed the poll, result is not showing. So how can i display the pol result in most recent block. Please any one help me out to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Poll module is making it to display only active poll as defined in these block

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function poll_block_info() {
  $blocks['recent']['info'] = t('Most recent poll');
  $blocks['recent']['properties']['administrative'] = TRUE;
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * Generates a block containing the latest poll.
 */
function poll_block_view($delta = '') {
  if (user_access('access content')) {
    // Retrieve the latest poll.
    $select = db_select('node', 'n');
    $select->join('poll', 'p', 'p.nid = n.nid');
    $select->fields('n', array('nid'))
      ->condition('n.status', 1)
      ->condition('p.active', 1)
      ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
      ->range(0, 1)
      ->addTag('node_access');

    $record = $select->execute()->fetchObject();
    if ($record) {
      $poll = node_load($record->nid);
      if ($poll->nid) {
        $poll = poll_block_latest_poll_view($poll);
        $block['subject'] = t('Poll');
        $block['content'] = $poll->content;
        return $block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As u can see this line in query ->condition('p.active', 1) it is causing these issue if u want u can remove this line and check,

But hacking core is not the right way in drupal better implement ur own block use the same code and make changes and display your block.
Just implement ur own block by using same code base.